# Add increment id in custom module

Tags: database, magento-1, orders, grid, sales-order

I have made a custom module for sellers.

There, I want to add a functionality of commission invoice. For the same, I want to have an `increment id` like in sales_order. The increment id should start with CI.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via an install script, and a class/model that will impliment the increment ID interface (`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Interface`).

Consider the below, which is an extract of the Mage_Sales install sql :

```
$installer->addEntityType('order', array(
    'entity_model'          => 'sales/order',
    'table'                 => 'sales/order',
    'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
    'increment_per_store'   => true
));

$installer->addEntityType('invoice', array(
    'entity_model'          => 'sales/order_invoice',
    'table'                 => 'sales/invoice',
    'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
    'increment_per_store'   => true
));

$installer->addEntityType('creditmemo', array(
    'entity_model'          => 'sales/order_creditmemo',
    'table'                 => 'sales/creditmemo',
    'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
    'increment_per_store'   => true
));
```

So, to start off, you'll need this :

```
$installer->addEntityType('commission_invoice', array(
    'entity_model'          => 'mymodule/commission_invoice',
    'table'                 => 'mymodule/commission_invoice',
    'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
    'increment_per_store'   => true
));
```

If you want a global incrementor (across stores), set`increment_per_store`1 to false, I believe you can get away with null for `table` if you don't need to store any further data, bu you do so lets model on the classic invoice...

So we have out entity_type and increment set up in the database, now for the entity itself, assuming you are using eav for your comission_invoices. This is kind of out of scope for increment ID's, but essentually you can set this up in install sql too with this method instead of the above :

```
$installer->installEntities(array(
    'commission_invoice_entity' => array(
        'entity_model' => 'mymodule/commission_invoice_resource',
        'table' => 'mymodule/commission_invoice',
        'increment_model' => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
        'increment_per_store' => 0,
        'increment_pad_length' => 0,
        'increment_pad_char' => '0',
        'attributes' => array(
            'increment_id', array(
                'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'backend'   => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_increment,
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Next, we need to impliment the Increment Interface in a model, its this model that actaully adds one and provides the increment ID's.

The idea is to take your "commission_invoice" model, that contains your invoice logic, and make it impliment the interface, this is how `sales/order` does it. Be aware that on the model's data collection the interrface will utilise "increment_id" (`getIncrementId()` and `setIncrementId()`) if you leave as standard.

So now for the model, I'm not going to Copy Paste the whole invoice or order model here, lets just jump in with the increment specific parts :

Here we see cod that will intercept the model being saved and set the increment ID on the model if it does not exist :

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{ 

    parent::_beforeSave();

    if (!$this->getIncrementId()) {
        $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType('commission_invoice')
            ->fetchNewIncrementId($this->getStoreId());
        $this->setIncrementId($incrementId);
    }

}
```

And there we have it, the built in IncrementId inrerface will do the rest for you.

Hope this helps! Disclaimer : i have not tried this code myself **yet**, I need to create a global simple incrementor for counting requests so I will confirm what I have written later...

**Edit : Added Tested Code**

Ok, so for my reasons I don't need an entity table, I just need the increment, so here's my working example :

/mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?php
$install = $this;
$install->startSetup();

$install->addEntityType('myitem', array(
    'entity_model'          => 'my_module/myitem',
    'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
    'increment_per_store'   => false,
));

$entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('myitem');
$entityStoreConfig = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_store')->loadByEntityStore($entityType ->getId(), 0);
$entityStoreConfig->setEntityTypeId($entityType ->getId())
    ->setStoreId(0)
    ->setIncrementPrefix("MYPREFIX")
    ->setIncrementLastId(100)
    ->save();

$install->endSetup();
```

This sets up my entity (as a basic `eav/entity` with no table), sets the Prefix to `MYPREFIX` and starting number to `100`.

Now we need the corrisponding model :

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Myitem extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    //this method simply adds one to the increment id an returns the new one
    public function getIncrementId(){
        return Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType('myitem')
            ->fetchNewIncrementId();
    }

}
```

Thats it, simple as can be. Obviously once you add your entire "commission_invoice" EAV model and tables it'll get a lot more complex. You might be best to move the code that retrieves a new ID tothe `beforeSave` overload method and wrap in an `if ( !$this->getIncrementId() ) {}` so ID's get added automatically on entity save.

Hope it helps!